# Apache not serving due to Sys_Sent

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have a mirror server for serving downloads to my clients and I am using tcp track to see the status of the requests.

I am facing this issue recently that the connections are established and then without serving anything to them the connection displays "SYS_SENT". This seems to be due to apache because if I restart httpd then the mirror works fine.

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this on my server ?

Comment: You sure about that 'SYS_SENT'? You might want to post the appropriate netstat output for better answers.

Comment: Sorry for the typo I meant SYN_SENT I have thousands of requests to my server so it is not possible to check what is happening on my client's side. Can this issue be resolved without having to contact my client ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean SYN_SENT.

This occurs when the SYN packet is sent by the initiating side of a TCP connection. This means a connection has been attempted but no response (SYN/ACK) received.

To sort that out, you'll need to also figure out what's going on at the client side of the connection.